# Java Random setSeed() not deterministic

Tags: java, random

I have a class called 'Face' that creates a static instance of java.util.Random:

```
public static Random random = new Random();
```

Then, in Main, I set the seed and get a random value:

```
Face.random.setSeed(1);
int rand = Face.random.nextInt(5);
```

The value of 'rand' is different every time I run the program, though. I need it to be the same every time. I thought setting a seed did this, but I must not understand correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `random` the same as `Face.random`? Are you sure? Because you said it's in `Main`, and one is a `Random` from `Face`; but what is the other?

Comment: and what is the value of `len`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the post. It should have been Face.random for both, and len = 5.

Comment: Post a small self-contained sample code where this is reproducible.

Comment: Haven't looked into the details of `setSeed`, but `new Random(seed)` will generate an instance that always creates the same sequence of numbers for the same seed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always *setting the seed* for every call, then it appears that the sequence of random numbers will be reset.

Try

```
random.setSeed(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int rand = random.nextInt(5);
    System.out.println(rand);
}
```